How to test for interaction between dichotomous repeated measures outcome and continuous moderator
In my dataset, participants were asked if they plan to make a purchase (yes/no) before and after a sales presentation. It is expected that people would be more likely to respond with an intent to purchases (i.e. “yes”) after the sales presentation than before.
However, we also have income data (continuous variable) and want to test if income interacts with time (before vs after sales presentation) to predict intent to purchase.
We expect that most people will respond “no” to intent to purchase before the sales pitch. However, we theorize that after the pitch, higher income people are more likely to change their intent to “yes” whereas low income people will still say “no”.
What type of test is appropriate in this context?
I know I can dichotomize income (e.g., median split) and run a chi square, but I would like to keep income continuous if possible.
Thanks!

I would personally make a data table containing 2 lines per subject (= potential buyer). Each buyer would have a unique ID, so this ID will be twice in this column.
Then I would have an other column (maybe called "intent") which will contain either 0 for no, 1 for yes.
Then an other column (maybe called "time") containing the information whether it is before or after the sales presentation.
And then an "income" column containing the value of the income. Similarly to subject ID, this column will contain twice the same value of income for the same ID.
Then I would test with a mixed-effects glm for a binomial distribution whether intent is explained by time in interaction with income. The subject ID will be a random factor since the measures are repeated fror each subject (i.e., before and after presentation are not independent from each other). The 'glmmTMB' package in R would be appropriate.
It would look a bit like this :
model<-glmmTMB(intent~time*income+(1|ID),family=binomial,data=data)

If this interaction is supported, it means there is indeed a different effect of the sales presentation according to income. If not, you might investigate whether intent is explained by additive effects of both these variables, or by only one of them.
